# Looking for a YA sci-fi book with a girl magically rescuing a boy trapped in a computer. 80s, I think

Tags: story-identification, magic, young-adult, computers

I can't recall either title or author, and think I read it in the 80s or VERY early 90s. The plot had a young girl discovering magical ability, and contacting a boy with similar talents. He ends up captured and imprisoned in a computer core, being used to power it. The girl has to touch points on a circle in a pentacle pattern before he completes the circle, or he'll be trapped and the bad guys take over the world or something. I remember the book used BASIC language commands, like GOTO10, for a programming loop. I seem to recall the book had a white cover with a very simple and small printed title with a small pentacle.

Comment: I know this book! I'm looking for it as well and I believe it was called something like "out of the dark" But I can't find it! I thought no one else even knew about it and was beginning to think I'd imagined the book! I remember her and her sister, and learning about meditation because of this book.

Answer (score 1):

"Out of the Dark World" by Grace Chetwin

[worldcat.org's summary](http://www.worldcat.org/title/out-of-the-dark-world/oclc/17588663):

> When a boy whose mind is trapped inside a computer program begins
>   appearing in her dreams, sixth grader Meg uses a hypnotic trance to
>   summon the sorceress Morgan le Fay for aid in freeing him.